# Game file parsing

Tags: notation

Does anyone  know which notation this is and how to parse it?

I tried to convert it to JSON, change "=" to ":" and other details,
but there may be an easier solution.

```
UnitBlueprint {
    AI = {
        BeaconName = 'UAB5102',
        TargetBones = {
            'UAA0107',
        },
    },
    Air = {
        AutoLandTime = 1,
        BankFactor = 0.1,
        BankForward = false,
        CanFly = true,
        CirclingDirChange = false,
        CirclingElevationChangeRatio = 0.25,
        CirclingFlightChangeFrequency = 15,
        CirclingRadiusChangeMaxRatio = 0.4,
        CirclingRadiusChangeMinRatio = 0.3,
        CirclingTurnMult = 1,
        KLift = 2,
        KLiftDamping = 2,
        KMove = 0.95,
        KMoveDamping = 2,
        KRoll = 1,
        KRollDamping = 1,
        KTurn = 1,
        KTurnDamping = 4,
        LiftFactor = 8,
        MaxAirspeed = 10,
        StartTurnDistance = 10,
        TransportHoverHeight = 3,
    },    
}
```

Comment: Looks like HOCON

Comment: Cover it to a json then map is the better way.

Comment: This is Lua,you can use lua to json

Answer (score 0):

Use json. First convert this string into JSON object:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject)parser.parse(stringToParse);
```

Comment: Code above it is not JSON